# Coordinate in LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx, coordinates

Hi i am learning libGDX these days, I followed [this example](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/tutorials/libgdx-physics), and I read this [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Coordinate-systems)

I dont really understand these line of code after adding `viewport`

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
super.resize(width, height);
extendViewport.update(width, height);
batch.setProjectionMatrix(orthographicCamera.combined);
}
```

And rendering

```
batch.begin();

banana.setPosition(0, 0);
banana.draw(batch);

banana.setPosition(100, 100);
banana.draw(batch);

batch.end();
```

Looking at the example, they still draw the banana in **bottom-left** of screen, I mean the (0, 0) point still in bottom-left of screen
[image]

While in my code, I think it changed the coordinate to **center** of screen, (0, 0) now is center of screen.

[image]

I am not clearly understand about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `ExtendViewport#update()`, you're not passing the third parameter (like the tutorial does), so it is centering the camera on 0,0 instead of positioning the camera so that 0,0 is in the lower-right corner.

If you change your call to be `extendViewport.update(width, height, false)` it should remedy the issue.

Comment: yes, you're right. I fixed it